# accessing foreignkeytables in LINQto EF query

Tags: entity-framework

I have some foreign key tables in my database(mySQL). Why are these not accessible in LINQ to EF? For example I have a table shippinglocationscontacts, why does that table NOT become part of the EF Model? How can I access these tables in LINQ to EF?

Comment: You're going to have to share how your entity model is set up.  Are you using Code First?

Comment: database generated set up

Comment: How are your entities set up?  Can you show some code?

Comment: default code generation from the T4 templates

Comment: You really should show some code in terms of how your entities are set up and how your context configuration is set up.  How are you linking your entities together?  Do you have configuration classes set up, are you using attributes, some mix of both, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I bet that `shippinglocationscontacts` is a junction table. It only contains `shippinglocationId` and `contactId` (or similar names). This is an EF feature. It maps junction tables as a many to many association between, in this case, shippinglocations and contacts.

So `contact` has a property `shippinglocations` and `shippinglocation` has a property `contacts`.

You don't manipulate the table directy. You add items to the collections (like `shippinglocation.contacts.Add(contact)` and EF will insert a record in the junction table.